# How to make CSS div width equal to browser width if element is inside wrapper element

Tags: css

What I have so far:

```
<style>
.wrapper {
    width:980px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.element {
    width:10000px;
    overflow:visible;
    margin-left:-2000px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-bottom:100px;
    border: 1px dotted green;
}
</style>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="element">
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8cyHR/

I want to remove horizontal scrollbar (.element must have the same width as browser's window width) but wrapper element still must be only 980px wide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question as I see it now drives my absolutely crazy, since it does not match your code at all. So, I've tried to work out multiple options for you.

**Cant get what do you want - Case #1**

Apply position:absolute or position:relative to the element, which will take it out of the normal flow, if you'd like to let .element be more than it's parent container. (have I understood you correctly? That's what you want?)

**What do you want (case #2):**
If you'd like .element to be as wide as browser (window?), why do you use width:10000px?? use absolute positioning (see case #1) and width:100%

**Case #3:**
if you don't want to see a horizontal scrollbar of an .element, than do overflow:auto, or overflow:hidden, instead of :visible (or simply remove it if it's not inherited).

**Case #4:**
If you'd like to hide horizontal scrollbar of the WINDOW that may occur when your document is less than 10000px wide, use case #2 or add overflow:hidden to the parent div

PS. Why should one want to use margin-left:-2000px? :-) Is it for demonstration purposes only? Hope so

Comment: thank You for Your time. Case #2 is correct one. I've updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8cyHR/1/ .element's left side still starts at .body element and not at .wrapper element

Comment: 1) Add "left:0" to absolute positioned element... And "top:0", if you need vertical positioning as well. 2)accept the answer if it fulfills your needs ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution...your CSS not withstanding is to take the specific div out of a wrapper. after all there is no reason why you can't have more than one wrapper.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div ></div>
</div>

<div class="element"> </div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div ></div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FDJdv/2/)